# R color palette with gradients with specific positions of the colors and specific transitions between the colors

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors

I have 4 colors that are optimized for color-vision-deficiency.

```
library(viridis)
viridis(4) -> colors
```

Now I would like to make a color scale (0-1) where these colors including a grey color are organized as follows:

grey from 0-0.6, colors[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R3Xet.png) from 0.6-0.69, colors[2] from 0.7-0.79, colors[3] from 0.8-0.89 and colors[4] from 0.90-1.

Between the colors there should be short transitions between the color for a segment of about 0.05

**Update:**
What I mean is a gradient color scale. It should looke like this:

[image]

Comment: you want a contant grey from 0 to 0.6 ? then a constant `colors[1]` from 0.6 to 0.7, etc?

Comment: Yes, but I want to set the position of the colors and the transition between the colors. I updated my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `colorRamp` as follows:

```r
gray <- "#666666"
viridisColors <- hcl.colors(4, "viridis")
colors <- rep(c(gray, viridisColors), times = c(30, 5, 5, 5, 5))
ramp <- colorRamp(colors)
```

Then `ramp` is a function associating a color to each number in `[0, 1]` in a way similar to your description. The color is given as `c(r, g, b)`.

The point is that `30 = 6x5`. If you use `times = c(60, 10, 10, 10, 10)`, you will get no transition at the `0.01` "granularity level". Here there is a small transition:

```r
n <- 200
x <- seq(0, 1, length.out = n)
colrgb <- ramp(x)
colhex <- rgb(colrgb[, 1], colrgb[, 2], colrgb[, 3], maxColorValue = 255)
h <- rep(1, n)
barplot(h, col = colhex, space = 0)
```

[image]

With `times = c(12, 2, 2, 2)`, the transition is longer:

[image]

Comment: Marvellous. Thank you. Can the ramp somehow be translated to ggplot2 plot (e.g., connect it with fill)? Anyway, I accepted the answer since I did not specify this in my question.

Comment: @ava Sorry I don't remember of `fill` works. Isn't there a `scale_fill_manual` function allowing to give the colors you want?

Comment: Yes, I also found some [hints](https://www.r-bloggers.com/2022/06/custom-colour-palettes-for-ggplot2/) how to connect `colorRampPalette` with `scale_fill_manual` but I could not make it run. I opened a new [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77199699/color-palette-with-gradients-with-specific-positions-of-the-colors-and-specific).

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?
Use [`gray`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/grDevices/html/gray.html) to create the gray color and put it at the beginning of the colors vector. The gray level can be any number in (0, 1), where 0 is black and 1 is white.

```r
library(viridis)
#> Loading required package: viridisLite

viridis(4) -> colors
gr <- paste0(gray(1/2), "FF")
colors <- c(gr, colors)
barplot(setNames(rep(1, 5L), letters[1:5]), col = colors)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-09-28 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

To assign the colors above to a vector of values in (0, 1), use `findInterval`. This is what function `assign_colors` calls.

```r
library(viridis)
#> Loading required package: viridisLite

# creates a vector of n viridis colors plus a 
# shade of gray color as the first vector element
make_colors <- function(n, grayshade = 1/2) {
  colors <- viridis(n)
  gr <- paste0(gray(grayshade), "FF")
  c(gr, colors)
}
assign_colors <- function(x, cut_points, colors) {
  i_colors <- findInterval(x, cut_points)
  colors[i_colors]
}

cut_points <- c(0, 0.6, 0.69, 0.79, 0.89, 1)

set.seed(2023)
x <- rbeta(10, 1/2, 1/2) |> setNames(letters[1:10])

colors <- make_colors(4L)
clrs <- assign_colors(x, cut_points, colors)
barplot(x, col = clrs, ylim = c(0, 1))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-09-28 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thank you very much! Could you probably give an example how the scale would look like for a heatmap or so? Like on https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/viridis/vignettes/intro-to-viridis.html with `geom_hex()`

Comment: And how could I add a transition between the colors for a segment of about 0.05?

Comment: Maybe my description is somehow misleading, it is not a discrete but a contiuous scale.