# Color palette with gradients with specific positions of the colors and specific transitions between the colors in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors

I just learned [how to make color palette with gradients with specific positions of the colors and specific transitions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77195305/r-color-palette-with-gradients-with-specific-positions-of-the-colors-and-specifi/77197593?noredirect=1#comment136093558_77197593) between the colors in base R.

[image]

```
library(grDevices)

gray <- "#666666"
viridisColors <- hcl.colors(4, "viridis")
colors <- rep(c(gray, viridisColors), times = c(30, 5, 5, 5, 5))
ramp <- colorRamp(colors)

n <- 200
x <- seq(0, 1, length.out = n)
colrgb <- ramp(x)
colhex <- rgb(colrgb[, 1], colrgb[, 2], colrgb[, 3], maxColorValue = 255)
h <- rep(1, n)
barplot(h, col = colhex, space = 0)
```

[image]

Is there a way to connect `ramp` with `ggplot2`?

I found some examples where `colorRampPalette()` was used with `scale_colour_manual` but I could not import my palette to a `ggplot`2 with that information. https://www.r-bloggers.com/2022/06/custom-colour-palettes-for-ggplot2/

Comment: I don't understand why you chose this approach. It looks like fundamentally you want a discrete color scale. Use `aes(color = findInterval(grouping_variable, breaks))` and then use `scale_color_manual`.

Comment: @Roland Thank you! Is it descrete if there are transitions between the colors? These transitions are very important for my setting.

Comment: please provide a reproducible ggplot2 example using `fill`

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21537782/how-to-set-fixed-continuous-colour-values-in-ggplot2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact you don't need `colorRamp`/`colorRampPalette` for a **ggplot2** graphic. Probably one of these functions is used in the built-in function `scale_colour_gradientn`. So, just choose the generating colors in the same way as the one given in my answer to the previous post, and use these colors in `scale_colour/fill_gradientn`:

```r
gray <- "#666666"
viridisColors <- hcl.colors(4, "viridis")
colors <- rep(c(gray, viridisColors), times = c(12, 2, 2, 2, 2)) # or c(30, 5, 5, 5, 5) for a shorter transition

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(
  iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width, colour = Petal.Length)
) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_colour_gradientn(colours = colors)
```

[image]

By default, **ggplot2** maps the values of the coloring variable to the range of this variable, but you can change that with the `limits` argument:

```r
ggplot(
  iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width, colour = Petal.Length)
) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_colour_gradientn(colours = colors, limits = c(0, 10))
```

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Many thanks! `ggplot2` [uses](https://github.com/search?q=repo%3Atidyverse%2Fggplot2%20ramp&type=code) `scales::colour_ramp`, i think that is similar to `grDevices::colorRamp`.